# Ruby - read each line in file to object and add object to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby and trying to read each line of a file.  I want to create an object called LineAnalyzer using each line and then add that object to an array called analyzers.

The code I am trying is

```
Class Solution 
    attr_reader :analyzers;

    def initialize()
      @analyzers = Array[];
    end

    def analyze_file()
      count = 0;

      f = File.open('test.txt')

      #* Create an array of LineAnalyzers for each line in the file

      f.each_line { |line| la = LineAnalyzer.new(line, count) }
          @analyzers.push la;
          count += 1;   
      end
    end
end
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciate!!

Comment: `Array[]` is not what you mean. `[]` is sufficient. Empty argument lists on methods are also omitted by convention, so it's simply `initialize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, this should work:

```
class Solution 
    attr_reader :analyzers

    def initialize()
      @analyzers = []
    end

    def analyze_file()
      count = 0;
      File.open('test.txt').each_line do |line| 
          la = LineAnalyzer.new(line, count) 
          @analyzers.push la
          count += 1
      end
    end
end
```

Little digressing from question, please note that - at most places in ruby you don't need `;`. Ruby is good so it doesn't complain about it, but its good to stay with the standard conventions.

Comment: Worth mentioning `;` is only necessary for collapsing multiple lines together, sometimes that's handy for things like `x.each { |y| y.do_thing; y.do_other }`. They shouldn't be present unless you're doing that even though they are otherwise ignored.

Comment: True. That's exactly and only the case in which I use `;` in ruby.